# Show validation error for blabk inputtext using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have created a vf page for validation errors.I want to use javascript to show the error"please enter a value" for an empty inputtext field.Please guide me with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validate()
    {
        if(document.getElementById('**inputTextId**').value == '')
        {
            alert("please enter a value");
        }
    }
</script>
```

You can use above code to validate input field on visualforce page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function validateField() {
    var isSuccess = true;
    var field = j$('[Id$=fieldId]');
    var fieldValue = j$(field).val();
    if (fieldValue == '' || fieldValue == null) {
        j$(field).addClass('error-occured');
        j$('.errorMsg').text('Please fill in this field'); //.erroMessage is the html tag where you'd want to show your error message
        isSuccess = false;
    }
    else {
         j$(field).removeClass('error-occured');

    }
    return isSuccess;
  }
```